# docker .env file reuse declared variables

Tags: docker, environment-variables, docker-compose

When I run docker-compose build I have a .env file to be used for building environment variables on my docker-machine like this:

```
COMPOSE_PROJECT_NAME=radar
ENV=production
DB_NAME=postgres
DB_USER=postgres
DB_PASS=sho1c2ov3Phezaimah7eb2Tii4ohkah8k
DB_SERVICE=postgres
DB_PORT=5432
C_FORCE_ROOT="true"
PGHOST=postgres
PGDATABASE=postgres
PGUSER=postgres
PGPASSWORD=sho1c2ov3Phezaimah7eb2Tii4ohkah8k
PGPORT=5432
```

If you have noticed the redundancy like the 'DB_NAME' and 'PGDATABASE' is the same.. Is there a way to avoid this?

Answer (score 3):

What about doing something like this in your `Dockerfile`?:

```
ARG DB_NAME
ENV DB_NAME=${DB_NAME} PGDATABASE=${DB_NAME} ...
```

**Test**

```
$ cat Dockerfile
FROM alpine:3.4

ARG DB_NAME
ENV DB_NAME=${DB_NAME} PGDATABASE=${DB_NAME}

RUN env
```

---

**Compose File Version 2 or higher!**

```
$ cat docker-compose.yml
version: '3' #'2' should work as well

services:
  docker-arg-env:
    build:
      context: .
      args:
        - DB_NAME
    command: env
```

---

```
$ cat .env
DB_NAME=world
```

---

```
$ docker-compose build
Building docker-arg-env
Step 1/4 : FROM alpine:3.4
 ---> 0766572b4bac
Step 2/4 : ARG DB_NAME
 ---> Running in a56be8426dd5
 ---> 4b1009ba9fad
Removing intermediate container a56be8426dd5
Step 3/4 : ENV DB_NAME ${DB_NAME} PGDATABASE ${DB_NAME}
 ---> Running in 5bbdd40e640e
 ---> 593105981a2a
Removing intermediate container 5bbdd40e640e
Step 4/4 : RUN env
 ---> Running in dadf204c7497
HOSTNAME=26ba10d264c2
SHLVL=1
HOME=/root
PGDATABASE=world
DB_NAME=world
PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin
PWD=/
 ---> 9632ee1e0e37
Removing intermediate container dadf204c7497
Successfully built 9632ee1e0e37
```

---

```
$ docker-compose up
Creating network "dockerargenv_default" with the default driver
Creating dockerargenv_docker-arg-env_1
Attaching to dockerargenv_docker-arg-env_1
docker-arg-env_1  | PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin
docker-arg-env_1  | HOSTNAME=5a6b51f4ecc7
docker-arg-env_1  | DB_NAME=world
docker-arg-env_1  | PGDATABASE=world
docker-arg-env_1  | HOME=/root
```

As you can see, PG_NAME and PGDATABASE are set during build-time and run-time.

**Without Compose**:

`docker build --build-arg DB_NAME=world .` and `docker run docker-arg-env:latest env` produce the same result.

**Update**

If you cannot (or don't want to) modify the Dockerfile try something like this:

```
$ cat .env
hello=world
```

---

```
$ cat docker-compose.yml
version: '2'
services:
  app:
    environment:
      - bar=${hello}
      - foo=${hello}
    image: someimage
```

---

```
$ docker-compose config
version: '2'
services:
  app:
    environment:
      - bar=world
      - foo=world
    image: someimage
```

See: https://docs.docker.com/compose/environment-variables/#the-env-file

Comment: Have you tried it? Unfortunately, it does not work on me

Comment: I have now ;-) Example is included in answer.

Comment: Oh, i completely forgot that you were using `docker-compose build`. Should have read the question again.

Comment: Yeah, I was about to comment that.. and I get the environment key-value on a .env file not on an arg option command line.. is it still possible?

Comment: Yes it is - but you have to use Compose File version 2 or higher.

Comment: Where did the world value came from on the docker-compose build method

Comment: from the `.env` file listed in  the answer.

Comment: oh ok, I'll try this one

Comment: What if I don't want to use DockerFile for this? Can I still do it in .env file by any other method?

Comment: @SameerMirji I'm not sure if I understand what you are trying to achieve. Are you talking about building Docker Images or something else?

Comment: @Martin: May be I was initially not entirely clear. My limitation is that I do not want to change the DockerFile (I only want .env file to have all the variables).

Comment: Yes, that's possible in combination with docker-compose. I'll update the answer.